# Cannot update value in mysql column

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm not sure what's happening. I'm trying to update a 'users' table with a value of 0 using a function that suspends a user. The column name is 'active', tinyint(1) with a default value of 0, and I've tried the query with 'active = 0', 'active = false', active = !active', 'active = NOT active', active = 'DEFAULT', none of these queries are returning an error, but none of them are updating the table... I've also tried binding the value in numerous ways to no avail...

```
function suspendUser($id){

        global $dbc;

        $sus = $dbc->prepare("UPDATE users SET active = 0 WHERE user_id = :id");
        $sus->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $sus->execute();

        if($sus->rowCount() > 0){
            return true;
            }
        else{
            return 'There was an error with your request.';
            }
        }
```

this is in my config file

```
try { 
$dbc = new PDO("mysql:host=$db_host;dbname=$db_name;charset=utf8",  $db_username, $db_password);
$dbc->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); }
 catch(PDOException $e){ 
echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage(); }

// create the error handler
    function my_error_handler($e_number, $e_message, $e_file, $e_line, $e_vars){
        global $debug, $contact_email;

        $message = "An error occurred in script '$e_file' on line $e_line:     $e_message";
        $message .= print_r($e_vars, 1);

    if($debug){
        echo '<div class="error">'.$message.'</div>';
        debug_print_backtrace();
        }
    else{
        error_log($message, 1, $contact_email);

        if(($e_number != 'E_NOTICE') && ($e_number < 2048)){
            echo '<div class="error">A system error occurred. We apologize for the inconvenience.</div>';
            }
        } 
    }

    set_error_handler('my_error_handler');
```

this is the javascript function

```
function suspendUser(uid){
        $.ajax({ url: 'lib/user-edit.php',
                data:{action: 'suspend', id: uid},
                type:'post',
                success: function(t){
                    $('#' + uid).prepend('<p>'+t+'<br>Sucessfully suspended</p>');
                    }
                });
        }
```

and then

```
if(isset($_POST['action'])){
        $action = $_POST['action'];
        }
    if(isset($_POST['id'])){
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        }
    if(isset($_POST['role'])){
        $role = $_POST['role'];
        }
    else{
        return 'There was an error with your request.';
        }

// define the function to execute based on the posted action

if($action == 'change'){
    changeRole($id);
    }
if($action == 'delete'){
    deleteUser($id);
    }
if($action == 'suspend'){
    suspendUser($id);
    }
```

I've added this to the function:

```
function suspendUser($id){

    global $dbc;

    $sus = $dbc->prepare("UPDATE users SET active = 0 WHERE user_id = :id");
    $sus->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $sus->execute();

     if (!$dbc->execute()) {
        $err = print_r($dbc->errorInfo());
        return $err;
         }

    if($sus->rowCount() > 0){
        $err = print_r($dbc->errorInfo());
        return $err;
        }
    else{
        $err = print_r($dbc->errorInfo());
        return $err;
        }
    }
```

I'm still not getting errors.

Comment: Get the *actual* error and let us know what that is.

Comment: like I said....  there is no error. Everything behaves as though the query was successful.

Comment: No, there are errors, you're just not reporting them.  [PDO Error Checking](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php)

Comment: there are several functions being run in this file, they're being called by an ajax function, which does print errors when they are happening... I know this because all of the functions are handled this way, and while I was creating them, I was getting errors returned.

Comment: You need to initialize your connection to be able to output errors. Follow @JayBlanchard link to get PDO Error Checking

Comment: Again, all of my other functions built exactly the same way DO return errors when there is one.

Comment: The only error you're catching is a connection error. You're not returning errors from the actual query.

Comment: updated with a more complete error handling function from my config file... not sure how else I need to show errors? Every other function returns and displays a very complete error message when one exists. If I'm missing something is there any way you could explain?

Comment: I've also attempted to return `PDOStatement::errorInfo()` in the function and no error was returned.

Answer (score 0):

If you are updating from zero to zero, the row count will be zero - because none of the rows changed.

Comment: From the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) *"rowCount() returns the number of rows affected by the last DELETE, INSERT, or UPDATE statement executed by the corresponding PDOStatement object. "*

Comment: I'm attempting to change the value from 1 to 0. The value in the db is currently 1.

Answer (score 0):

Oddly... the issue was solved by moving the

```
if($action == x)
```

statements to the

```
if(asset($_POST['action'])){
  if($action == x){}
}
```

not sure why that was an issue.... I wasn't getting errors because the function wasn't being called. Other functions were being called...